# I want my code to resize the image using seek bar before saving it in android. How can i do this?

Tags: android

I want to give the size to an image after capturing it but before save. I want seek bar to give the size to an image and then compress the image to that size. As I am new in android so Please help!

**My code is:**

```
public class ImageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;

private ImageView imageview;
SeekBar sb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image);

    sb=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekbar1);
    sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){
        int progressChangedValue=0;

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                                      boolean fromUser)
        {
            progressChangedValue = progress;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
        {
            Toast.makeText(ImageActivity.this, "progress starts",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
        {
            Toast.makeText(ImageActivity.this, "Seek bar progress is :" + progressChangedValue,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });

    this.imageview = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
    Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);

    photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);

        }
    });
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestcode, int resultcode, Intent data) {
    if (requestcode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultcode == RESULT_OK) {

        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageview.setImageBitmap(photo);
        UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
        String randomUUIDString = uuid.toString();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"UUID is"+randomUUIDString,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

Comment: After getting Bitmap, use `Bitmap resizedBitmap = createScaledBitmap(Bitmap src, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, boolean filter);`

Comment: @AkshayBhat Okay i got that. But how can i fetch the value from seek bar. As i need seek bar for alteration in size.

Comment: Create a member variable and set that variable the value in on progress changed. In onactivity result you can get the progress.

Comment: @AkshayBhat thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the max progress:

```
seekBar.setMax(200);
// or with the imageview's size: 'seekBar.setMax(imageview.getWidth());'
// if 'getWidth()' returns 0, you need to get it in a thread (with 'post()')
```

Now, you could initialize the progress (if you don't want to overhead 200 for example):

```
seekBar.setProgress(seekBar.getMax());
```

Then, with the `onProgressChange` state in the listener, you set the new width/height.
Assuming you have an image with equals width and height, max value to 200, you have to do:

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        imageview.getLayoutParams().width = progress;
        imageview.getLayoutParams().height = progress;
        imageview.requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { }
});
```

That's it! Now, you have to save the changed dimensions on the `Bitmap`, you should create a new Bitmap with the ImageView values as follows:

```
Bitmap finalBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,
                    imageview.getWidth(), imageview.getHeight(), false);
```

This is not the final solution and it needs more tests and tunings, but it's a working clue to help you to get what you want.